# Do the ticket machines at the RER station at Paris CDG airport accept €20 notes?

Tags: trains, tickets, france, cdg

At Paris Charles-de-Gaulle airport, can I use a €20 note to buy a €10 RER ticket?

Comment: Which ticket buying machine?

Comment: It is hard to imagine that a machine that takes cash doesn't give change back. (Surely if it was even legal it would be more prevalent). But you will probably get your change in coins (5 × 2 euro) rather than as a 10-euro note.

Comment: @MJeffryes, at CDG airport there are ticket vendor machines

Comment: A greater risk is that the machine doesn't take notes _at all_, though.

Comment: @HenningMakholm, Is there option to get coin by exchanging 20 euro note from helping authorities there in the vendor machine. Because I have only 50 euro and 20 euro notes and I am coming from India

Comment: I would just buy a coffee and give them a 50 EUR note. You should get loads of change then.

Comment: Tickets for what?! Presumably not plane tickets, perhaps you mean train tickets?

Comment: @mdewey, thanks. I have less budged and every thing at the airport is costly.

Comment: @MJeffryes, Yes from CDG airport to Montparnasse gare i.e. RER tickets of 10 euro

Comment: In any case if the ticket machine does not accept the notes you can buy yout tickets at the train station office so it will be fine anyway :)

Comment: @stbr, ok nice suggestion

Comment: @HenningMakholm machines that don't return change are moderately common for parking, and existing but rare for snack food in the UK.

Comment: Contrary to the US for instance, vending machines which take notes are quite rare in France (and probably in most of Europe, I’d say, though this may be an overstatement). Coins and cards are the common accepted modes (more and more often only cards, actually). RATP (which operates the Paris metro and most bus and tram lines, and part of the RER network, but not the branch to CDG) has some, but I don’t think SNCF (which operates RER in CDG) does.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The RER vending machines will probably only accept coins and card payments and no bank notes at all. At the airport, there are however staffed ticket counters where you can buy a ticket and pay cash and get proper change.